# jQuery - How to prevent the form from posting data after an alert message is shown?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to prevent the user from posting the form data if the birth date is not filled. I have used some script as shown below to prevent the user from posting the data when the birth date is not inserted but the form is still posted.

The below is my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TutorRegister", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{       
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
        </div>
        <span class="clearfix"></span>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </div>
        <span class="clearfix"></span>


        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <label>Date of Birth</label>
            <div class="input-group date" id="dtp">
                <input name="Birthday" id="Birthday" class="form-control" onfocus="$(this).next().trigger('click')" onkeydown="event.preventDefault()" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Birthday)
        </div>
        <span class="clearfix"></span>                

        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <input id="btnRegister" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

The below is the script:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnRegister").click(function () {
                if (document.getElementById('Birthday').value == "") {
                    alert("You need to fill Date of Birth field!");
                    return;
                }
            })
        })           
    </script>
}
```

The code above does show the alert and after clicking on ok I want the form not to be posted.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you not just binding to a model property with the `[Required]` attribute? this is all handled out of the box in mvc

Comment: even better than `e.preventDefault()` we can use `return false` method as that's recommended to use over `preventDefault()` in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cancel the default action with the event's `preventDefault` method:

```
        $("#btnRegister").click(function (e) {
            if (document.getElementById('Birthday').value == "") {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("You need to fill Date of Birth field!");
                return;
            }
        })
```

NB: You need to specify the function parameter to get access to the event object.